# Rearrange order of geom_segment y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

**Problem:** Want to order ggplot by length of geom_segment.

**Data**

```
swimplot_response 

 SUBJECT            RESPONSE ORD_RESP  STARTRESP    ENDRESP ORD DEATH  MAX_RESP
1        01            On Study        1  0.0000000 88.9000000   1     1 94.483871
2        01      Stable Disease        2  0.0000000  9.2333333   2     1 94.483871
3        01    Partial Response        3  9.2333333 21.0333333   3     1 94.483871
4        01   Complete Response        4 21.0333333 62.0333333   4     1 94.483871
5        01 Progressive Disease       -1 62.0333333 88.0000000   5     1 94.483871
6        01     Off Study/Alive        0 88.0000000 94.4838710   6     1 94.483871
7        02            On Study        1  0.0000000 93.5806452   1     1 93.806452
8        02      Stable Disease        2  0.0000000  1.9000000   2     1 93.806452
9        02 Progressive Disease       -1  1.9000000 93.5806452   3     1 93.806452
10       02     Off Study/Alive        0 93.5806452 93.8064516   4     1 93.806452
11       03            On Study        1  0.0000000  4.1290323   1     1  5.774194
12       03      Stable Disease        2  0.0000000  0.6666667   2     1  5.774194
13       03 Progressive Disease       -1  0.6666667  4.1290323   3     1  5.774194
14       03     Off Study/Alive        0  4.1290323  5.7741935   4     1  5.774194
15       04            On Study        1  0.0000000  2.5666667   1     1  5.607143
16       04      Stable Disease        2  0.0000000  2.5666667   2     1  5.607143
17       04 Progressive Disease       -1  2.5666667  5.6071429   3     1  5.607143
18       05            On Study        1  0.0000000 11.0645161   1     1 19.833333
19       05      Stable Disease        2  0.0000000  3.0000000   2     1 19.833333
20       05 Progressive Disease       -1  3.0000000 11.0645161   3     1 19.833333
21       05     Off Study/Alive        0 11.0645161 19.8333333   4     1 19.833333
```

2. Then I subsetted by `MAX_RESP`. In this code I thought I had solved the issue of arranging the dfs by `MAX_RESP`.

```
subj_18mos_resp <- swimplot_response %>%
  group_by(SUBJECT) %>%
  filter(MAX_RESP >= 18) %>%
  arrange(desc(MAX_RESP))

subj_18mos_resp

subj_18mos <- unique(subj_18mos_resp$SUBJECT)

subj_18mos_bev <- swimplot_bev %>%
  subset(SUBJECT %in% subj_18mos) %>%
        group_by(SUBJECT) %>% 
        arrange(ORD, .by_group = TRUE)

subj_18mos_steroids <- swimplot_steroids %>%
  subset(SUBJECT %in% subj_18mos) %>%
        group_by(SUBJECT) %>% 
        arrange(ORD, .by_group = TRUE)

subj_18mos_dose <- swimplot_dose %>%
  subset(SUBJECT %in% subj_18mos) %>%
        group_by(SUBJECT)

subj_18mos_resp

# A tibble: 66 x 8
# Groups:   SUBJECT [16]
   SUBJECT RESPONSE            ORD_RESP STARTRESP ENDRESP   ORD DEATH MAX_RESP
   <chr>   <chr>                  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 01      On Study                   1      0      88.9      1     1     94.5
 2 01      Stable Disease             2      0       9.23     2     1     94.5
 3 01      Partial Response           3      9.23   21.0      3     1     94.5
 4 01      Complete Response          4     21.0    62.0      4     1     94.5
 5 01      Progressive Disease       -1     62.0    88        5     1     94.5
 6 01      Off Study/Alive            0     88      94.5      6     1     94.5
 7 02      On Study                   1      0      93.6      1     1     93.8
 8 02      Stable Disease             2      0       1.9      2     1     93.8
 9 02      Progressive Disease       -1      1.9    93.6      3     1     93.8
10 02      Off Study/Alive            0     93.6    93.8      4     1     93.8
# ... with 56 more rows
```

3. I also tried to convert the `SUBJECT` to factor and level by the current order, but this did not work. (Error message included below.)

```
subj_18mos_resp$SUBJECT <-  factor(levels = subj_18mos_resp$SUBJECT) 

Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [2] is duplicated
```

4. I also tried including `subj_18mos_resp` within the `ggplot(aes())`

My plot code is included below, as well as images of the example plots

[image: "Full" plot example]

"Full" swim plot code (with dose, bev, steroid use) for subjects with overall survival >18mos

```
SwimmerPlot_18mos_full <-  ggplot() +
  
  theme_classic() +
  
  geom_vline(xintercept = 6, colour = "black", linetype = "longdash",
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  
  geom_segment(data = subj_18mos_resp, aes(x = STARTRESP, xend = ENDRESP, 
                                                  y = SUBJECT, yend = SUBJECT,
                                                  colour = RESPONSE),
               size = 4, show.legend = TRUE) +
  
  scale_colour_manual(values = response_color) + 
  
  geom_segment(data = subj_18mos_steroids, aes(x = STARTROIDS, xend = ENDROIDS, 
                                                y = SUBJECT, yend = SUBJECT,
                                                colour = STEROIDS),
               
               size = 2, linetype = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  
  geom_segment(data = subj_18mos_bev, aes(x = STARTBEV, xend = ENDBEV, 
                                           y = SUBJECT, yend = SUBJECT,
                                           colour = BEV),
               size = 1, linetype = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  
  geom_point(data = subj_18mos_dose, aes(x = DUR, y = SUBJECT, 
                                          fill = TREATMENT),
             shape = 25, size = 2.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  
  labs(title = "Phase 1 GBM Swim Plots",
       subtitle = "Data from study [redacted]",
       caption = "Subjects with OS of >18 mos.",
       color = "Response") +
  
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Duration in Months", breaks = seq(0,90,10)) +
  
  ylab(label = "Subject ID") +
  
  scale_fill_discrete() +
  
  geom_vline(xintercept = 6, colour = "black", linetype = "longdash",
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  
  geom_text(aes(x=DUR, y=SUBJECT, label = TREATMENT), data = subj_18mos_dose,
            nudge_y = 0.5, nudge_x = 0.5, size = 2.5) +
  
  guides(fill = FALSE)

SwimmerPlot_18mos_full
```

[image: Response only example]

Subjects >18 mos response only

```
SwimmerPlot_18mos <-  ggplot() +

  geom_segment(data = subj_18mos_resp, aes(x = STARTRESP, xend = ENDRESP, 
                 y = SUBJECT, yend = SUBJECT,
                 colour = RESPONSE),
             size = 4, show.legend = TRUE) +
  
  scale_colour_manual(values = response_color) + 

  labs(title = "Phase 1 GBM Swim Plots",
       subtitle = "Data from study [redacted]",
       caption = "Subjects with OS of >18 mos.",
       color = "Response") +
  
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Duration in Months", breaks = seq(0,90,10)) +
  
  ylab(label = "Subject ID") +
  
  #Add dashed line at 6 month mark
  geom_vline(xintercept = 6, colour = "black", linetype = "longdash",
             show.legend = TRUE) +
  
  theme_classic()

SwimmerPlot_18mos
```

Comment: Levels can't be repeated in the `levels` argument, use `subj_18mos_resp$SUBJECT <-  factor(levels = unique(subj_18mos_resp$SUBJECT))` (added `unique()`)

Comment: I shortened your question by deleting everything up to and including the merge - it seems like `swimplot_response` has all the relevant data and you don't have trouble creating it, so no need to show all the preliminary work. Even then, do we need that whole data and the subset code, or just the subset?

Comment: And as an FYI, for inline code you only need one backtick. Three backticks is for multiline code blocks.

Comment: But basically, if you have the order of (unique) IDs, put that in a vector `subj_order`, then you can reorder the factors in each data frame, `data$SUBJECT = factor(data$SUBJECT, levels = subj_order)`. Alternately, you can specify it in the y scale so you don't have to bother modifying all the data frames, `+ scale_y_discrete(limits = subj_order)`

Comment: Just to clarify - so for each bar you need the order of geom draw is based on the length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much Gregor Thomas!

I ended up arranging the MAX_RESP by ascending order and re-factoring, since ggplot builds levels in ascending order as default. Your comments led me to the following solution (changes marked by `#comments`):

```
subj_18mos_resp <- swimplot_response %>%
  group_by(SUBJECT) %>%
  filter(MAX_RESP >= 18) %>%
  arrange(MAX_RESP) #Changed from arrange(desc(MAX_RESP))

subj_18mos_resp

subj_18mos <- unique(subj_18mos_resp$SUBJECT)

subj_18mos_resp$SUBJECT <- factor(subj_18mos_resp$SUBJECT, levels = subj_18mos) 
#Re-specified levels from the unique vector produced when arranged by increasing MAX_RESP

subj_18mos_bev <- swimplot_bev %>%
  subset(SUBJECT %in% subj_18mos) %>%
        group_by(SUBJECT) %>% 
        arrange(ORD, .by_group = TRUE)

subj_18mos_steroids <- swimplot_steroids %>%
  subset(SUBJECT %in% subj_18mos) %>%
        group_by(SUBJECT) %>% 
        arrange(ORD, .by_group = TRUE)

subj_18mos_dose <- swimplot_dose %>%
  subset(SUBJECT %in% subj_18mos) %>%
        group_by(SUBJECT)
```

[image: Solution Plot]